# How to place objects in one line [Bootstrap 5]

Tags: bootstrap-5

I need it in one line, how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bootstrap 5 grid system (ensure you are including the Bootstrap 5 css url)

Example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

Your code would look, something like this:

```
<div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
    <div class="nav-item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <form class="d-flex" action="search.php" method="get">
                    <input class="form-control me-2 px-3" type="search" placeholder="Search" name="search" aria-label="Search">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginmodal">Login</button>                    
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#signupmodal">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also put the signup button into a column on its own.

Comment: I tried using it but the result is the same.

Comment: Share what you tried

Comment: @dxDark I've updated my answer with more detail and a sample for you

Answer (score 0):

Add your buttons inside the form, or add d-flex to your nav-item class

Like this:

```
 <div class="nav-item d-flex">
```